# Laravel separating app, bootstrap, and vendor directories from public and having app still function

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel

I have my document root set to `/var/www`

Inside of `/var/www` I have wordpress files and directories for the frontend Wordpress Website.

File structure looks like this:

```
www/
    laravel/
        app/
        bootstrap/
        vendor/
        laravel files
    portal/
        this should be the contents of the public folder instead named portal
    wordpress files
```

How can I separate the public directory from the main laravel application, and still have the application function without breaking the wordpress website?

I've tried editing all of the directories in bootstrap/paths.php, and portal/index.php but it's not doing what I'm trying to achieve.

My `portal/index.php` file has these lines edited:

`require '../laravel/bootstrap/autoload.php';`

`$app = '../laravel/bootstrap/start.php';`

In my `bootstrap/paths.php` file I've set these values equal to these directories:

`'app' => '..',`

`'public' => '../../portal',`

`'base' => '..',`

Can this be done?  Sub-domain is not an option.  I know there must be a way to do this.

Comment: in bootstrap/paths.php you should only change 'public' path. 'app' should remain - 'app' => __DIR__.'/../app', and same goes for 'base' - 'base' => __DIR__.'/..'

Comment: Changed them back still doesn't work.

Comment: what do you get, any error?

Comment: I have an .htaccess file in /var/www for the wordpress to work, and one in /var/www/portal for Laravel to work.

Comment: change 'public' => '../../portal' 
to 'public' => __DIR__.'/../../portal',
that should work, unless you have something wrong in htaccess or maybe you need to recompile - run php artisan dump-autoload

Answer (score 0):

for this to work you only need to change index.php in public (portal) folder to

```
require __DIR__.'/../laravel/bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../laravel/bootstrap/start.php';
```

and laravel/bootstrap/paths.php

```
'app' => __DIR__.'/../app',
// here you only change public path to
'public' => __DIR__.'/../../portal',
'base' => __DIR__.'/..',
'storage' => __DIR__.'/../app/storage',
```

Next is to check yout .htaccess file.
If thats seems ok, then try to regenerate laravel/bootstrap/compiled.php by running

```
php artisan optimize --force
```

Other then that, check your error log.